# .net core how to get week datetime list by datetime range

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I hope get week datetime list by datetime range,I tried the following code get number of weeks per month.

```
var start = new DateTime(2021, 6, 09);
var end = new DateTime(2021, 7, 01);

end = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(end.Year, end.Month));

var diff = Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
                             .Select(e => start.AddMonths(e))
                             .TakeWhile(e => e <= end)
                             .Select(e => Convert.ToDateTime(e.ToString("yyyy-MM")));

foreach (var item in diff)
{

   DateTime dateTime = item;
   Calendar calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
   IEnumerable<int> daysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, calendar.GetDaysInMonth(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month));
   List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> weeks = daysInMonth.Select(day => new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, day))
                .GroupBy(d => calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday))
                .Select(g => new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(g.First(), g.Last()))
                .ToList();
}
```

Executing the above code I got the following result,get all the weeks of each month。

```
2021-06-01 2021-06-06
......
2021-07-26 2021-07-31
```

I want to count the week from my start date 2021-06-09 to the end date 2021-07-01, like this.

```
2021-06-09 2021-06-13
2021-06-14 2021-06-20
2021-06-21 2021-06-27
2021-06-28 2021-07-01
```

how to changed my code

Comment: How do you define a week? `2021-06-09 2021-06-13` doesn't follow any normal definition. And your code - while very complicated, - does it give you correct results?

Comment: @Felix 2021-06-09 and 2021-07-01 is input param ，The 9th is Wednesday. I only need to get the 13th Sunday as the week and Monday as the start of the week, but the week starts with the start date I passed in. June 28 is Monday and July 1 is Thursday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce the desired output:

```
var start = new DateTime(2021, 6, 09);
var end = new DateTime(2021, 7, 01);
// If you want to get the first week complete, add this line:
//DateTime currDate = start.AddDays(1-(int)start.DayOfWeek);
// Otherwise, use this one
DateTime currDate = start;
while(currDate <= end){
    var dayOfWeek = (int)currDate.DayOfWeek;
    var endOfWeek = currDate.AddDays(7 - dayOfWeek);
    //If you want the complete last week, omit this if
    if(endOfWeek > end)
    {
        endOfWeek = end;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{currDate:yyyy-MM-dd} {endOfWeek:yyyy-MM-dd}");
    currDate = endOfWeek.AddDays(1);    
}
```

output:

```
2021-06-09 2021-06-13
2021-06-14 2021-06-20
2021-06-21 2021-06-27
2021-06-28 2021-07-01
```

Comment: thank you ,If I want to get the whole week of the start time2021-06-07 2021-06-13，Full week of end time2021-06-28 2021-07-04，how to changed code

Comment: @beiduoan I edited my answer, changing the code a bit so you can choose if you want the full first and last weeks.